# How can I find out which projects build errors originate from in TFS Build?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I may be missing something here, but if a build fails- I can't see anywhere in the Summary or Log that outlines which projects the errors (and warnings) originate from.

For example, we have a solution with about 15 projects in. Recently, we started getting the following build error:"Controllers\ProfileController.cs (10): The type or namespace name 'Models' does not exist in the namespace 'XXX'". I could not see any mention of the project that the error originated from, and this caused me lost time as I spent time checking the references in one project without realising that we had a second project with a controller with the same name.

Comment: When you are looking at the build output there's a link to the full log file. It's labeled "View Log File". You will probably find that helpful if you weren't aware of it.

Comment: Ah yes, I can see it now. Obvious when you know where to look really. I was expecting something along the lines of a 'Project' column similar to Visual Studio's Error List pane. If you put that in an answer, I'll mark it as the answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TFS build output has a link near the top of the build output labeled "View Log File". This is the full MSBuild output that you're used to from visual studio output window. You will be able to get the details you need from that log file.